# Change trace behavior Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have this 5x5 eye array which I supposed to calculate the sum from k=1 using 'trace' keyword but turned out I have to change the trace start position, how do I that?.

```
import numpy as np
# TODO: Trace an eye  

eye_0 = np.eye(5,5, k=1)
trace_eye = np.trace(eye_0)
print(eye_0)
trace_eye 

[[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
0.0
```

Comment: I did not understand your question. What were supposed to get?

Comment: [Docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trace.html) should help

Comment: @Carlos Adir ,I was approaching for 4.0 as my output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Numpy.trace` has an offset parameter:

```
np.trace(eye_0, offset = 1)
```

This will return 4 in your case.